# Variable is undefined when submitting form?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a form where I choose a date/year from a datepicker and depending
on what the user choose it bring up data from a table or a blank form.
I have two different submit buttons on the form depending on what is
chosen in the datepicker.

```
<cfset counter_2=0>


<form method="post" name="loantype" action="cse_execoffice_datepicker_test.cfm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
....................code
    <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick(this.counter_2=1)></p>

    <cfelse> 
...more code

<p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick(this.counter_2=0)></p>     

</form>
```

The problem im having is when I submit the form ONCLICK is not setting counter_2 to either '0 or 1'.

I want it to set it to 0 or 1 because depending on what is submitted.

```
<cfif FormSubmit eq "FormSubmitted">

<cfif counter_2 eq 0>
...code....
</cfif>
<ciif counter_2 eq 1>
...code..
</cfif>
</cfif>
```

The error I get is
Variable COUNTER_2 is undefined. 
I have set the variable outside the form and even try it inside.

Do i have to set the counter_2 somewhere else?

Comment: I suggest transferring all that logic to the code where you process the form.

Comment: `<input ... onclick(this.counter_2=0)>` isn't valid syntax, it should be `<input ... onclick = "this.counter_2=0;">`.  You're also mixing server-side CF variables and client-side JS variables, incorrectly.

Comment: +1 what duncan said. `<cfset counter_2=0>` happens on the ColdFusion server. `<input ... onclick = "this.counter_2=0">` happens on the client (user's computer).

Comment: @duncan so changing to correct syntax wont solve the problem? i should do what Dan Bracuk suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing languages and incorrectly implementing them to boot. I think you are trying to do something like this so your form handler can see the counter_2 value?
Try this:

```
<form method="post" name="loantype" action="cse_execoffice_datepicker_test.cfm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <input type='hidden' name='counter_2' id='counter_2' value=''>
  <cfif...>
    <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="document.getElementById('counter_2').value=1"></p>
  <cfelse>... 
    <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="document.getElementById('counter_2').value=0"></p>     
</cfif>
</form>
```

This will allow a form field to be submitted with the value based on which element they clicked on.